# nginx not starting server

Tags: node.js, nginx

I just installed nginx on a server on Scaleway.

Following the tuts I found, I did this:

- created a node app running on port 3000
- and modified the site-enabled default file to test it.

Here is what my file looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}


server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mydomainename;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://SERVER_PRIVATE_IP:3000;
        }
}
```

When I try to access any domaine pointing on my server, they just hit the default nginx welcome index file.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following:

1) edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and put:

```
server {
  server_name _ 127.0.0.1;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html;
}
```

2) have file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sitename` with content :

```
server {

    server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;
    root /home/sitename/public; # feel free to modify

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|mp3|xml)$ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location / {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

3) symlink it:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/sitename /etc/nginx/site-enabled/sitename
```

4) restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

have fun (:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since it's a node app, do I really need the  root, index etc...?
The app is running on port 3000 already. When I remove default configurationt hen all the domains point to the node app on port 3000, which at the end doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Better have sitename.conf and put contents that I wrote in answer. Then symlink or copy  it to sites-enabled folder. In real it must work if You defined sitename properly. Root and index is not necessary, but it's better have for serving static files by nginx not by proxy_pass.

Comment: Tried a lot of solutions but all end up sending all domains to the same index